# Cannot compile latest release google-api-dotnet-client. - GoogleApi.Core

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

Build Log
    ------ Build started: Project: GoogleApis.Core, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(161,60): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(161,69): error CS1001: Identifier expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(162,31): error CS1044: Cannot use more than one type in a for, using, fixed, or declaration statement
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(162,48): error CS1002: ; expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(175,32): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(175,56): error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(178,13): error CS1519: Invalid token 'do' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(180,63): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(182,30): error CS1519: Invalid token '!=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(184,37): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(185,30): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(187,17): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(219,84): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(229,21): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(240,17): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(122,41): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(122,60): error CS1001: Identifier expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(122,96): error CS1002: ; expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(125,48): error CS1519: Invalid token '!=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(125,59): error CS1520: Method must have a return type
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(125,103): error CS1001: Identifier expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(125,104): error CS1002: ; expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(127,60): error CS1001: Identifier expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(127,83): error CS1001: Identifier expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(127,107): error CS1001: Identifier expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(127,108): error CS1002: ; expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(128,21): error CS1519: Invalid token '.' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(128,22): error CS1520: Method must have a return type
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(128,37): error CS1031: Type expected
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(130,13): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(137,24): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(156,17): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(179,27): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
    C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(183,5): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

```
Compile complete -- 34 errors, 0 warnings
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
------ Build started: Project: GoogleApis, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Core.dll' could not be found

Compile complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
------ Build started: Project: GoogleApis.Auth, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Core.dll' could not be found

Compile complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
------ Build started: Project: GoogleApis.DotNet4, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Core.dll' could not be found

Compile complete -- 2 errors, 0 warnings
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
------ Build started: Project: GoogleApis.Auth.Mvc4, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Core.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Auth\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Auth.dll' could not be found

Compile complete -- 2 errors, 0 warnings
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
------ Build started: Project: GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.DotNet4\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Core.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Auth\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Auth.dll' could not be found

Compile complete -- 3 errors, 0 warnings
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
------ Build started: Project: GoogleApis.Tests, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.DotNet4\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Core.dll' could not be found

Compile complete -- 3 errors, 0 warnings
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
------ Build started: Project: GoogleApis.Auth.Tests, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Tests\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Tests.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Core.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Auth\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Auth.dll' could not be found
```

Compile complete -- 3 errors, 0 warnings
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 8 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I have downloaded the latest source and then have tried to recompile the entire solution. I get numerous errors on two files.

I am running Windows7 with both .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 installed. I am using VS2010 SP1 and trying to build to .NET 4.0.

I have discovered in trying to use the GoogleAPI Client in Access (using COM Interop) that there is an issue. I was trying to recompile the entire project so I could make changes to API to see if I could determine what was going on. I wrote a .NET dll which I then used in a .NET test application and everything works perfectly. (Add/Update/Find/Delete Calender Entries). As soon as I try and use in Access (using Com Interop) I get an error.

I was able to step into the code and found the exact line which error happens.
It appears to be some difference between the IList when ran the two different ways. I am trying to see if it can easily be repaired.

Again what is confusing that it works perfectly on the same machine if ran using the .NET Windows form and Dll (either in VS2010 IDE or a compiled exe) but fails if I try and use the dll in access. The dll is registered correctly because I can step into in using VS2010 and I have code which runs successfully to build the EventAttendee collection.

I have to use COM because I am trying to replace an integration from an Access Application to Outlook with Access to Google Calendar.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Brent McCaw
brent@brentmccaw.com

Comment: 1. Can you add the error log (It's really hard to understand why you are getting "Syntax error, '(' expected". 2. What Google API do you want to use eventually (YouTube, Calendar, etc.)? 3. Why do you want to use COM?

Comment: The Error log is attached:

Comment: To clarify. I am trying to use COM Interop to allow me to use a VB.Net dll which I developed to insert/update/find and delete google calender entries. I ran into an error when trying to use the dll in Access aplication so I was trying to determine what error was by rebuilding API and determining what the problem is but I cannot compile the 1.8.1 because of the errors.

Comment: Ideally just want it to work in COM Interop but I think I will have to get API 1.8.1 compiled and fix what is going wrong. It errors on a specific line in:  var handler = CreateHandler(args); in public ConfigurableHttpClient CreateHttpClient. There is no error condition just exits.

Comment: As a note same error happens if I try and use in vb6.

Comment: The client library supports VB.NET. Why COM?

Comment: To use a VB.NET dll in Access (VBA) you have to do it using COM Interop. You add it as a reference in the VBA project. I have done this with other API interfaces written in .NET. My DLL is registered correctly and I can step into the API but I cannot make any changes because I cannot recompile the project. If you have another way I can do this, I will go that way.